# Using jQuery to make turn a <span> to and <input> and back

Tags: jquery, html

So I have a page where so fields are s and when a user clicks on them they change to inputs to allow changing their values. When the user clicks outside the input it changes back to a span. Here is the code I'm using:

```
$(function () {
$('.txtToInput').live('click', function () {
    var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text','class': 'txtToInput', 'name': 'aname', 'value': $(this).html()});
    $(this).parent().append(input);
    $(this).remove();
    input.focus();
});

$('.txtToInput').live('blur', function () {
    var span = $('<span />', {'class': 'txtToInput'});
    $(this).parent().append($(span).html($(this).val()));
    $(this).remove();
});
});
```

This works pretty well but there is one problem: when a user highlights the text in the input the content jump outside the input and the element cannot be changed back to a span. Any ideas what is causing this and how to fix?

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QNR5z/) demonstrating this behaviour.

Comment: Why not have an input element and a span? At any instance one of them is hidden. When a blur event is triggered on the input, you update the text or inner HTML of the span element.

Comment: @Terry that's just what I was suggesting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed:

```
textbox = false;
$(function () {
    $('.txtToInput').live('click', function () {
        if (!textbox) {
            var input = $('<input />', {
                'type': 'text',
                'class': 'txtToInput',
                'name': 'aname',
                'value': $(this).html()
            });
            $(this).parent().append(input);
            $(this).remove();
            input.focus();
            textbox = true;
        }
    });

    $('.txtToInput').live('blur', function () {
        if (textbox) {
            var span = $('<span />', {
                'class': 'txtToInput'
            });
            $(this).parent().append($(span).html($(this).val()));
            $(this).remove();
            textbox = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QNR5z/1/

You just need to check if the object is in "input" version or in "span" version, because the problem is, although the object is in "input" version, but if user clicks the object the code creates a new textbox

Answer (score 4):

It's fiddly to manipulate elements that appear and disappear from the DOM, and potentially requires event delegation (i.e. using `.live` as you are, or the preferred `.on` method).

Consider putting both elements in the DOM, and just using `.show()` and `.hide()` to determine which one is visible.

Comment: That is an elegant solution, however later on I extract the value of the parent element and strip out html tags. This method would result in having the text content twice, or I would need additional regex to remove the entire `input` including it's contents before submission

Comment: @harryg would a `:visible` filter when you extract the contents fix that?

Answer (score 1):

A really good way of not doing it all over again is to use `x-editable`. See [here](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/)

Comment: @harryg do you mean the link doesn't open, coz for me it does. If not, you can google x-editable and the first link should ideally be the one.

Comment: Yeah, the site must have been down when I tried it - it's fine now! X-editable looks good but I actually ended up going for [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable). Seems to be quite similar except it allows inline editing. AJAX is built right in too.